# Scrape formulas from excel file and convert them to R formulas

Tags: r, regex, excel

I got a task, where I have an excel file, with multiple sheets and various formulas. The sheets are linked between each other in many formulas.

What I was thinking to do was first to convert the excel in multiple CSVs and then finding all the formulas by looking up at the cells that start with '='. The thing I am struggling is to convert an excel formula such as: "=C2*xyz!D3/xyz!C4"

The final output should be a final data.frame or data.table containing all the codes/names of the formulas and the formulas converted in R syntax.

Comment: Parsing into R expressions will probably require a bit of work but you can try `XLConnect::getCellFormula` or `tidyxl::xlex` to extract cell formulae.

Comment: it's not clear how you would like to collect these R formulas or what they would look like.

Answer (score 0):

R formulas need the input data to be defined as a list. but in excel is was defined as per cell.

Since you are only (I assume) interested in 'some' list and not the full 'per cell' data,it'll be a waste to translate all formula to R.

Instead, have a seat back.. and look which data is the real input cell (or in R, the input list).. Then look how it was transformed/linked to other sheet, and trace till the output table. Once you got the draft algo, then re-writing the whole story(data relation) in R will not be as hard.

Hope it helps.

p/s : I'm proposing a method as a solution, not the full solution (since there is no sample data/file provided). ( :